# Rails, refactoring controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

Can you help me for refactor and DRY that? I have no ideas. Thanks.

```
if request.xhr?
  render :json => {
    :status => true,
    :location => root_url + "/projects",
    :message => I18n.t("project.destroy")
  }
else
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t("project.destroy")
  redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could overwrite redirect_to in application_controller.rb like this

```
def redirect_to(options={}, response_status={})
  if request.xhr?
    render :json => { :status => true, :location => options, :message => flash[:notice] }
  else
    super
  end
end
```

and then keep using

```
flash[:notice] = I18n.t('project.destroy')
redirect_to projects_path
```

in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can do but

```
message = I18n.t('project.destroy')

return render :json => {
         :status => true,
         :location => "#{root_url}/projects",
         :message => message
       } if request.xhr?

flash[:notice] = message
redirect_to :action => :index
```